# Dates from posts vs dates from Google Search indexes are incompatible

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, google

Recently, when I have been searching for some subject on Google Search, I started to come across this date incompatibility.

This is a sample search, the date index from Google Search is, `16 April 2017`, and we always take this as the date when the question asked:

[image]

However when you inspect the post, *[Exception handling in Controller (ASP.NET MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046351/exception-handling-in-controller-asp-net-mvc)*,
you will see it has no relation with this date either in its question or answers.

As up-to-dateness is very important for some specific languages (.NET Core, React, Angular etc), I always check the dates from the Google Search index, so I started to feel tedious because of this inconsistency.

**UPDATE**

and the google search result
Here I got a similar behaviour today;
This is the original SO link [SQLExpress instance seems to be absent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839655/sqlexpress-instance-seems-to-be-absent)

and the google search result,

[image]

Can't see any relation with the date in google index and any date in question.

**Note:** If it is important my culture is `tr-TR`

Comment: No repro. All the dates I see are indeed the last activity date of the posts. Google did not return that question that you highlighted for me.

Comment: I can post here samples as I come across. The above is one of them. By the way, the dates google return are the dates when the questions were asked.(and what it should be for all of them) So, we are not expecting a dynamic date.  here.

Comment: What is *"Angular vs"*? Or do you mean *"Angular, etc."*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen etc right, corrected it.